# Jquery Ui Tabs Current Container display Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

First please visit my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VsqQ3/

Currently the first three tabs ( `tab 1`, `tab 2`, `tab 3`) are in display by default, and when I click on `next>` : `tab 4`, `tab 5`, `tab 6` are being in displayed.

**What I want:** I want to display `tab 4`, `tab 5`, `tab 6` by default. How can I get that?

```
$(".wrapper #tab1,.wrapper #tab2").tabs({active: 0}).tabs({
            collapsible: false,
            hide: {
                    effect: "slideUp",
                    duration: 20
            },
            show: {
                    effect: "slideDown",
                    duration: 200
            }
    });

    var all = $('.wrapper .main').addClass("passiv");
    var prev = $('.wrapper .prev');
    var next = $('.wrapper .next');
    var tab_count = all.length-1;
    var currentContainer = -1;

    prev.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();   

        if (currentContainer != 0) {
            currentContainer -= 1;
            ctrlcontent(currentContainer);
        }
    });

    next.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (currentContainer < tab_count) {
            currentContainer += 1;
            ctrlcontent(currentContainer);
        }
    }).trigger('click');

    function ctrlcontent(index_to_show) {
       all.removeClass("active").addClass("passiv");
       all.eq(index_to_show).removeClass("passiv").addClass("active");

       if (index_to_show == 0) prev.hide();
       if (index_to_show == tab_count) next.hide();
       if (index_to_show > 0) prev.show();
       if (index_to_show < tab_count) next.show();
    }


    $(function() {
            $( ".wrapper .inner" ).buttonset();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for the following line:

```
    var currentContainer = -1;
```

you can change this to

```
    var currentContainer = Math.floor(all.length / 2) - 1; // -1 needed as your indexing seems to start at -1 rather than 0
```

and it should always start it on the middle container

http://jsfiddle.net/VsqQ3/5/

Comment: Is it dynamic? What if I want to display last three tabs?

Comment: just use the index of your tabs starting at -1 - `-1` for first three, `0` for second and `1` for third

Comment: It would be better for me if you show an example (jsfiddle example), as I am new to jquery

Comment: There is a fiddle in the answer above, just play with the `currentContainer` (line 17) variable and switch in the values in the above comment and see what happens when you press run

Answer (score 1):

Just add  `next.click();` to your code :)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VsqQ3/6/)

`next.click().click();` for last 3 tabs :)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VsqQ3/7/)

Comment: Is it dynamic? What if I want to display last three tabs?